# Temporary table committing the transaction in sybase

Tags: java, sql, sybase

I am doing a bulk insert using sybase temporary table approach  (# table name).  This happens in a transaction. However this operation is committing the data transaction. ( I am not doing a connection.commit myself).  I don't want this commit to happen since I might have to roll back the entire transaction later on.  Any idea why insert using temp table is committing the transaction withought being asked?. How do I fix this issue ?

The sql is something like

```
select * into #MY_TABLE_BUFFER from MY_TABLE where 0=1; 
load table #MY_TABLE_BUFFER from 'C:\temp\123.tmp' WITH CHECKPOINT ON; 
insert into MY_TABLE on existing update select * from #MY_TABLE_BUFFER; 
drop table #MY_TABLE_BUFFER;
```

And I am using `statement.executeUpdate()` to execute it

Figured out that its due to temp table not participating in transaction and doing a commit.
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Please show us some code and format it properly. Did you set [auto commit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29) to false?

Comment: You say you use `statement.executeUpdate()`. Do you call it from some other code? From Java for instance?

Comment: @cularis. Yes. its set to false. @ Nivas yes. from java code

Answer (score 4):

Sybase is funny about using user-specified (aka explicit) transactions in conjunction w/ the use of #temp tables (where the temp table is created **while in the transaction**). For better or worse, Sybase considers the creation of a #temp table (including via 'select into' statement) to be a DDL statement in the context of tempdb. In the editor, w/ default server/db settings, you'll get an error when you do this.

As a test, you could try setting the 'ddl in tran' setting (in the context of the tempdb database) to true. Then, see if the behavior changes.

Note, however, that permanently leaving that setting in place is a bad idea (per Sybase documentation). I'm proposing it for investigative purposes only.

The real solution (if my assumption of the problem is correct) likely lies in creating the #temp table first, then beginning the transaction, to avoid any DDL stmts in the scope of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

sp_dboption tempdb, 'ddl in tran',true

the above shuld work,even am also not able to create /update #tables when proc created with anymode.